# Make DOM elements from array of string elements and then join the result for render()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

An array of "keyCombo" objects is defined as shown below, and the intention is to render the data as styled lines in a React component's `render` method:

```
let items = [{"keyCombo": ["⌘","0"]}, {"keyCombo": ["⌘","Ctrl", "1"]}]

tokbd = (keyCombo) => {
  let styledKeys = keyCombo.map(key => <kbd>{key}</kbd>)
  return <span>{styledKeys.join(" + ")}</span>
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {items.map(item => <span>{this.tokbd(item.keyCombo)}</span>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'd like to get:

[image: expected result]

but instead, I get

`[object Object] + [object Object]` (and)
`[object Object] + [object Object] + [object Object]`

How can I combine the characters in the `keyCombo` arrays into:

"(styled element) + (styled element) + (styled element)"

and not:

"styled (element + element + element)"

where even the `+` characters get inadvertently styled too?

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(styledKeys)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join() method joins all elements of an array (or an array-like object) into a string and returns this string. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) This is why you are getting `[object Object]`.

You can try use reduce without second argument instead :

```
  tokbd = (keyCombo) => {
      let styledKeys = keyCombo.map(key => <kbd>{key}</kbd>).reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ' + ', curr])

      return <span>{styledKeys}</span>
    }
```

**[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vqrq685k95)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Object.entries to convert object into array of [key, value] pairs. This then allows you to use all the array transformation methods.

```
tokbd = (keyCombo) => {
  return Object.entries(keyCombo).map(k => <kbd>{k[0].join(' + ')}</kbd>)[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Array#join on an array of objects, the `.toString()` method of each item is called. The `.toString()` method of object returns `[object Object]`.

**Note:** the `tokbd` method should actually be a separate component. I've named the component `KeyCombo`.

**Option 1 - CSS pseudo elements to insert the +:**

```js
const items = [{"keyCombo": ["⌘","0"]}, {"keyCombo": ["⌘","Ctrl", "1"]}]

const KeyCombo = ({ keyCombo }) => (
  <div>{
    keyCombo.map(key => <kbd key={key}>{key}</kbd>)
  }</div>
)

const App = ({ items }) => (
  <div>{
    items.map((item, index) => <KeyCombo key={index} {...item} />)
  }</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App items={items} />,
  demo
);
```

```css
kbd:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: '+'
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

**Option 2: Create an array for each key, flatten, and slice the last**

```js
const items = [{"keyCombo": ["⌘","0"]}, {"keyCombo": ["⌘","Ctrl", "1"]}]

const KeyCombo = ({ keyCombo }) => (
  <div>{
    [].concat(...keyCombo.map(key => [
      <kbd key={key}>{key}</kbd>,
      <span key={`${key}+`}>+</span>
    ])).slice(0, -1)
  }</div>
)

const App = ({ items }) => (
  <div>{
    items.map((item, index) => <KeyCombo key={index} {...item} />)
  }</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App items={items} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```